# M2 Add a block to the contact page

Tags: magento-2.1, static-block

I have created a block which contains my company name, address, telephone etc. How can I add this block to my contact page http://www.extenderstore.com.au/contact/ ? 
I would like it located under the contact form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to a cms static block, it can be added with a quick layout update.

> app/design/{{Vendor}}/{{Theme}}/Magento_Contact/layout/contact_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="contact-store-info" before="contactForm">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">{{block_identifier}}</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: It appears on the top. How can I position it under the contact form?

Comment: change `<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="contact-store-info" before="contactForm">` to `<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="contact-store-info" after="contactForm">`